# Filtering a Custom Adapter on listview is not working properly in android?

Tags: android, listview, filtering, android-filterable

I have a array adapter as follows. and I have implemented a Filterable, but then also when I type in EditText nothing happens.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom> implements Filterable{
    private ArrayList<Custom> entries;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    private qrusers qrusers;
    CustomFilter customFilter;
    private String[] udis;
    ArrayList<String> userid= new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean[] checkBoxState;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Custom> entries,String []udis) {
        super(context,0,entries);
        this.entries = entries;
        this.context= context;
        this.udis=udis;
        checkBoxState=new boolean[entries.size()];
        this.qrusers =(qrusers) context;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView item1;
        public TextView item2;
        public CheckBox chek;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {

            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.checkboxlist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
            holder.item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
            holder.chek=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checboxlist);



            v.setTag(holder);


        }

        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();


        }
        holder.chek.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
        holder.chek.setTag(udis[position]);
        holder.chek.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            private String s;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    checkBoxState[position]=true;
                    //  isChecked=true;
                    s=(String)v.getTag();
                    Log.e("IDDDDDDDD", s);

                    userid.add(s);
            Log.e("ADDED ID", userid.toString());
            }
                else{
                    checkBoxState[position]=false;
                    s=(String)v.getTag();
                    userid.remove(s);
                    Log.e("Removed ID", userid.toString());
                }
                }

        }
        );
        final Custom custom = entries.get(position);
        if (custom != null) {
            holder.item1.setText(custom.getcustomBig());
            holder.item2.setText(custom.getcustomSmall());

        } 
        return v;
        }
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (customFilter == null) {
            customFilter = new CustomFilter();
        }
        return customFilter;
    }


    public ArrayList<String> getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(ArrayList<String> userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    private class CustomFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.values=entries;
                 results.count = entries.size();

            }
            else{

                ArrayList<Custom> newValues = new ArrayList<Custom>();
                for (Custom i : entries){

                     if (i.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                            newValues.add(i);
                 }
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
 if (results.count == 0){

                 notifyDataSetInvalidated();
             }
             else{

                 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<Custom> lst = (ArrayList<Custom>)results.values;
                 ArrayList<Custom> itemsList = new ArrayList<Custom>(lst);
                 //this.items=mItems;
                entries =itemsList;              
                notifyDataSetChanged();
             }

        }


    }
}
```

and in my activity I am using this piece of code.

usersearch1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                    s=usersearch1.getText().toString();
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    Log.e("ALPHABETS", usersearch1.getText().toString());
                    //sendadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }
```

Comment: When you do the filtering the results are set on the entries list, but the adapter isn't based on that list, it's based on the list that you passed in the constructor. In the `publishResults()` method call `clear()` then in a `for` loop iterate over `itemlist` and add each item with the `add()` method of the adapter.

Comment: @Luksprog can you please explain the same using code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `publishResults()` method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    if (results.count == 0){
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    } else {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Custom> lst = (ArrayList<Custom>)results.values;
        ArrayList<Custom> itemsList = new ArrayList<Custom>(lst);

        entries = itemsList;              
        clear();
        for (Custom item : entries) {
            add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2699728 That's because you don't return the results from `performFiltering()`. In that method just before the `return results;` line add the lines `results.count = newValues.size(); results.values = newValues;`.

Comment: @user2699728 Did you actually logged the code in `performFiltering()` method to see if you have any values in the `newValues` list? When you type something in the `EditText` the `ListView` remains with the current values or you just don't see any filtered values in the `ListView`?

Comment: I am not getting any values in newValues. I checked it.

Comment: @user2699728 Then you obviously don't have any filtered values. Check your `if` condition(`if (i.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))`) something is wrong there. Make sure that `toString()` in the `Custom` class returns the proper data on which to filter.

Comment: Now I am getting data in newValues, but it is not getting filtered?

Comment: Means my listview is not changing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46842/discussion-between-user2699728-and-luksprog)

Comment: Hey ,I can successfully filter the list now, but the point is that when the editext gets blank orignal listview is not updated, it shows only the filtered data

Comment: @user2699728 When doing a filtering operation always keep a list with the original values. So in the constructor of `CustomAdapter` create another list named `originalValues` remember to copy the values don't just assign the `entries` to it like you do with the `entries` list. Then in the `Filter` class when the constraint is null or a 0 length string use the `originalValues` to restore the entire list(again make a copy of `originalValues`, don't modify it!).

Comment: more or less content, sometimes run, sometimes not run